# How to set maximum concurrent threads while dequeuing ConcurrentQueue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, throttling, concurrent-queue

I have one thread responsible for enqueuing and one thread responsible for dequeuing. However, the frequency of the data being enqueued far surpasses the time needed to dequeue + process the data.
When I did the following, I ended up with a huge delay in data processing:

```
public void HandleData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Queue.TryDequeue(out item);
                ProcessData(item);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Next I tried, processing the data in separate tasks, but this ended up affecting other tasks in the project since this treatment ended up taking up most of the resources allocated to the application and generating a high thread count.

```
public void HandleData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Queue.TryDequeue(out item);
                Task.Run(() => ProcessData(item));
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I tried the following :

```
public void HandleData()
{
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Queue.TryDequeue(out item);
                if (taskList.Count <= 20)
                {
                    Task t = Task.Run(() => ProcessData(item));
                    taskList.Add(t);
                }
                else
                {
                    ProcessData(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            taskList.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to have solved the problem, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it? a way to set a maximum concurrent threads number while dequeuing?

Comment: Don't use a ConcurrentQueue to begin with. Use a `Channel` instead. The container can't control the number of threads that access it anyway. What you can do is use a set number of workers/tasks. In .NET 6 this is almost trivial with `ParallelForEachAsync`

Comment: Another alternative to consider is the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), specifically the [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) subset.

Comment: you want to is SemaphoreSlim to control the amount of threads which can be executed in any given time, googling this is bound to give u some results. @PanagiotisKanavos ParallelForEachAsync does not handle a queue type architecture.

Comment: @Seabizkit that's why I said Channel for the container. Processing isn't the *container's* concern, it's the worker's. The other option is an ActionBlock. There's no reason to hand-code throttling when there are better options available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ConcurrentQueue` isn't the proper container, especially since it doesn't provide asynchronous operations. A better option would be using an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-6.0) or a [Channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) combined with [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/parallelforeachasync-in-net-6).

**Using an ActionBlock**

An ActionBlock combines both an input queue and workers to process the data asynchronously. The workers process the data as soon as it's available. Using an ActionBlock, you can create a block with a set number of workers and start posting data to it. The block will use only the configured number of worker tasks to process the data:

```
ActionBlock<Data> _block;

public void Initialize()
{
    var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20
    }

    _block =new ActionBlock(ProcessData,options);

}
```

Data/messages are posted to the block using either the [Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.post?view=net-6.0) or [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync?view=net-6.0) methods. When there's no more data, the [Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.complete?view=net-6.0) method tells the block to shut down after processing any pending items. We can await for pending items to complete by awaiting the [Completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.completion?view=net-6.0) property

```
public async Task Produce(CancellationToken cancel)
{
    while(!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var data=ProduceSomething();
        _block.Post(data);
    }
    _block.Complete();

    await _block.Completion;
}
```

**Using Channel**

Another option is to use a `Channel` instead of a `ConcurrentQueue`. This class is equivalent to an asynchronous ConcurrentQueue that [provides an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=net-6.0) that can be iterated with [await foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#await-foreach). You can create a specific number of workers to read from either the container itself, or through the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` stream. In .NET 6, the last part is a lot easier using `Parallel.ForEachAsync` with a fixed degree of parallelism option:

```
async Task<ChannelReader<T>> Producer(CancellationToken token)
{
    var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<T>();

    var writer = channel.Writer;

    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var someDate = ProduceData();
        await writer.WriteAsync(someData);
    }
    writer.Complete();
    
    return channel.Reader;
}    


async Task Consumer<T>(ChannelReader<T> input,int dop=20)
{
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop
    };
 
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(input.ReadAllAsync(), options,
                                data=>ProcessData(data));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution is to use an [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) for the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library, which is part of the .NET standard libraries (from .NET Core onwards). This component invokes an action on each item it receives. It has its own input queue internally, which by default is unbounded, and processes the items with a configurable [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism), which by default is 1. Here is how you could use it. First you create the block:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Item>(item =>
{
    ProcessData(item);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded // Configurable
});
```

Then you feed it with work to do, at any moment you like:

```
block.Post(new Item());
```

Finally, when you are about to terminate the program, you mark the block as completed, and then `await` (or `Wait`) the block to complete for a clean termination:

```
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

**Note:** In case the `ProcessData` fails once, the `ActionBlock<T>` will stop accepting more items (the [`Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.post) method will return `false` instead of `true`). If you want it to be fail-proof, you should `catch` and handle all errors inside the `ProcessData` (or inside the `Action<T>` that calls the `ProcessData`).